# Run script after everything else before poweroff

Tags: systemd, shutdown

How can I configure systemd to run a script
at the end of the power-off processing
(the thing that, twenty+ years ago,
would have been called “the power-off runlevel”)? 
The script should be the last thing to run
before the computer is powered off. 
Ideally, the script should not be run if the system is going to reboot.

I tried `Before=shutdown.target`,
but this causes the script to run at the beginning of shutdown.

I am aware that, at the last point before power-off,
the system is so close to being shutdown that it’s effectively unusable:
there are no mounted file systems any more,
no network and no other services.

The kernel seems to have a problem
with switching off the spinning hard drive. 
While the system is powered off,
I hear that the disk head is retracting (unsafe power off). 
The SMART "Power Off Retract Count" attribute is increasing. 
I know there's a fix for this, but it’s not released yet. 
So I want to use the `hdparm -Y /dev/sda` command as a workaround.

So I guess I need my script to run before the root file system is unmounted,
but after all other disk I/O activities (including sync) are complete.

Comment: what is that script doing? You *are* aware that at the last point before poweroff, there's no mounted file systems anymore, no network and no other services?

Comment: (and runlevels don't exist anymore, but I think we get what you mean; the problem really is that I don't quite understand what you *need*; that's why I'm asking what your script is doing)

Comment: I'm not sure many people has such use case, so probably you should do some own research: I would check systemd sources. If they call poweroff (or shutdown) command, just override them (either as configuration if possible, or as true command) to execute a script which will call the poweroff. If systemd is using directly the kernel, so a program, else: you should probably modify the sources (systemd calls `kill` several time, so you cannot just wait you are the last one)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Kernel has a problem with switching off the spinning hard drive. While the system is powered off I hear that the disk head is retracting (unsafe power off). SMART "Power Off Retract Count" attribute is increasing count. I know there's a fix for this but not released yet. So I think to use `hdparm -Y /dev/sda` command as workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> So I guess I need my script to run before the root file system is unmounted, but after all other disk I/O activities (including sync) are complete.

That's probably not going to work because unmounting a filesystem, even a sync'ed one, can still cause I/Os and will just wake the disk again. (Offhand I'm not sure whether systemd even does a separate sync – I believe it just lets the umount call handle that, as umount always implies a full sync/flush anyway.)

With systemd, you can run custom scripts at this point by putting them in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` (as documented in *systemd-shutdown(8)*), but as long as they're being run from the same disk, they most likely won't have the effect you want.

It might be better to use what systemd calls the "shutdown initramfs":
if you prepare the `/run/initramfs` directory before shutdown (e.g. using a service that's part of shutdown.target), then systemd will pivot back to the in-memory /run filesystem which will then be able to fully unmount the old root filesystem, and *then* it can ask the HDDs to spin down before triggering the actual power-off.

(Arch Linux's mkinitcpio has a `mkinitcpio-generate-shutdown-ramfs.service` that could be used as an example; I believe Dracut now has support for this as well.)

Comment: Using a shutdown ramdisk can resolve the issue. Although a different kernel was used to solve my problem, this solution could be useful for other shutdown-related cases.